# Cartesian join (all vs all) with Numpy matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Suppose two Numpy matrix of same number of columns:

```py
matrix_1 = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]

matrix_2 = [
    [10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15],
    [16, 17, 18]
]
```

I'd like to obtain the following result:

```py
result = [
    ([1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12]),
    ([1, 2, 3], [13, 14, 15]),
    ([1, 2, 3], [16, 17, 18]),
    ([4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12]),
    ([4, 5, 6], [13, 14, 15]),
    ([4, 5, 6], [16, 17, 18]),
    ([7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]),
    ([7, 8, 9], [13, 14, 15]),
    ([7, 8, 9], [16, 17, 18])
]
```

How could I get that? I couldn't find a fast way to do the join. I've used [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) from Pandas but I'd like to make a Numpy pure solution to prevent overhead

Comment: `from itertools import product; list(product(matrix_1, matrix_2))`?

Comment: I have a numpy way to get this `array([[ 1,  2,  3, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 1,  2,  3, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 1,  2,  3, 16, 17, 18],
       [ 4,  5,  6, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 4,  5,  6, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 4,  5,  6, 16, 17, 18],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 16, 17, 18]])` but not yet with the third dimension as in your example. I assume, you want the result exactly like you have written?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response! @QuangHoang: that's what I need, but I'm looking for a Numpy alternative

Comment: @mcrot: I need the exaclty format I specified. Thanks to both for your comments! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard way is:

```
from itertools import product; 
list(product(matrix_1, matrix_2))
```

`numpy` doesn't have this functionality but I found a couple of ways which works on modified types of arrays:

```
dt = np.dtype('i,i,i')
matrix_1 = np.array([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)], dtype=dt)
matrix_2 = np.array([(10, 11, 12), (13, 14, 15), (16, 17, 18)], dtype=dt)
```

**First trick:**

```
list(np.broadcast(matrix_1[:,None], matrix_2[None,:]))

[((1, 2, 3), (10, 11, 12)),
 ((1, 2, 3), (13, 14, 15)),
 ((1, 2, 3), (16, 17, 18)),
 ((4, 5, 6), (10, 11, 12)),
 ((4, 5, 6), (13, 14, 15)),
 ((4, 5, 6), (16, 17, 18)),
 ((7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12)),
 ((7, 8, 9), (13, 14, 15)),
 ((7, 8, 9), (16, 17, 18))]
```

**Second trick:**

*First variation:*

```
np.stack(np.meshgrid(matrix_1, matrix_2), axis=-1).reshape(-1, 2)

array([[( 1,  2,  3), (10, 11, 12)],
       [( 4,  5,  6), (10, 11, 12)],
       [( 7,  8,  9), (10, 11, 12)],
       [( 1,  2,  3), (13, 14, 15)],
       [( 4,  5,  6), (13, 14, 15)],
       [( 7,  8,  9), (13, 14, 15)],
       [( 1,  2,  3), (16, 17, 18)],
       [( 4,  5,  6), (16, 17, 18)],
       [( 7,  8,  9), (16, 17, 18)]],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')]
```

*Second variation:*

```
np.stack(np.meshgrid(matrix_1, matrix_2), axis=-1).swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(-1, 2)

array([[( 1,  2,  3), (10, 11, 12)],
       [( 1,  2,  3), (13, 14, 15)],
       [( 1,  2,  3), (16, 17, 18)],
       [( 4,  5,  6), (10, 11, 12)],
       [( 4,  5,  6), (13, 14, 15)],
       [( 4,  5,  6), (16, 17, 18)],
       [( 7,  8,  9), (10, 11, 12)],
       [( 7,  8,  9), (13, 14, 15)],
       [( 7,  8,  9), (16, 17, 18)]],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

#### Update

As per comments, output of ***second trick*** is array of shape `(matrix_1.shape[0]**2, 2)`, however, wanted output sould be of shape `(matrix_1.shape[0]**2, 2, matrix_1.shape[1])`. It happens because groups of items are manipulated as single items inside structured array, so resulting array has `matrix_1.shape[0]**2` pairs of items. It can be fixed borrowing from an answer of [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64613276/). So general solution is:

```
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as recfunctions
n, m = 16, 23
dt = np.dtype(','.join('i'*m))
matrix_1 = recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured(np.arange(n*m).reshape((n,m)), dtype=dt)
matrix_2 = recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured(np.arange(n*m).reshape((n,m)) + 10, dtype=dt)
out = np.stack(np.meshgrid(matrix_1, matrix_2), axis=-1).swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(-1, 2) #shape = (256, 2)
new_out = recfunctions.structured_to_unstructured(out) #shape = (256, 2, 23)
```

Comment: I'm trying all your tricks but with my initial data which has a shape of `(16, 23)` I'm getting `(256, 2, 23)` for the first standard attemp (which is correct!). But unfortunatelly I'm getting `(5888, 2)` for the first trick, `(135424, 2)` for the second (first variation) and `(135424, 2)` for the second (second variation). Why it could be happening?

Comment: @Genarito That's why groups of items are manipulated as single items in a structured array. I asked how to fix it another question so I can come back with a new solution.

Comment: Note that this fix can be done for second trick only because I'm still not sure how to convert list into array in first trick

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments. I'm using, for the moment, `np.array(list(product(matrix_1, matrix_2)))` to make a Numpy array from the list

Comment: I'll give a try to the new proposal and measure their times to keep the fastest. Thank you so much!