# How to convert array into special items of structured array and revert it back?

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, array-broadcasting

I want to perform some numpy methods on items of structured array instead of numbers. So, for example, while working with array of integers of shape (4, 3), I need to convert it to array of items of length 3 and perform some operations as it were a single one dimensional array of shape (4,). These conversions itself, unfortunately, looks really complicated for me. Let's take another example:

```
n, m, r = 2, 3, 4
array = np.arange(n*m).reshape((n,m))
dt = np.dtype(','.join('i'*m))
arr1 = np.array([tuple(x) for x in array], dtype=dt)
>>> arr1
array([(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

Then I call some methods on it, let it for the sake of simplicity be `np.tile` (but they might be completely different):

```
arr2 = np.tile(arr1[:,None], r)
>>> arr2
array([[(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 2)],
       [(3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5)]],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

I want to convert it into this array instead:

```
array([[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]],
       [[3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]]
```

I have two questions:

1. How to convert `array` to `arr1` (a bunch of special items) without iteration?
2. How to convert `arr2` (a bunch of special items) back to array of single items I want?

Comment: "I want to perform some numpy methods on tuples instead of numbers. " That is **absolutely** not what you are doing. You are using a structured array. It is not an "array of tuples instead of numbers"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Alright, I'll fix it. It is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy` provides a helper functions to do this:

```
>>> n, m, r = 2, 3, 4
>>> array = np.arange(n*m).reshape((n,m))
>>> import numpy.lib.recfunctions as recfunctions
>>> recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured(array, dtype=np.dtype(','.join('i'*m)))
array([(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

And in the other direction:

```
>>> import numpy.lib.recfunctions as recfunctions
>>> recfunctions.structured_to_unstructured(arr2)
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]],

       [[3, 4, 5],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [3, 4, 5]]], dtype=int32)
```

In this *particular* case, if the original array is `dtype=np.int32`, you could use a view:

```
>>> array = np.arange(n*m, dtype=np.int32).reshape((n,m))
>>> structured_view = array.view(dtype=np.dtype(','.join('i'*m)))
>>> structured_view
array([[(0, 1, 2)],
       [(3, 4, 5)]], dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

The advantage of a view is that it create a new array. Of course, this can be a *disadvantage* if you mutate your view and don't expect the original array to change as well.

In the reverse, it doesn't handle the shape you want, but you could always reshape:

```
>>> arr2.view(dtype=np.int32)
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5]], dtype=int32)
```

Using views can get tricky, fast.

Comment: @mathfux you could have also used `numpy.view` but that has a bunch of land-mines, you have to be aware about packing, etc. It works for the simplest cases like you have here, though, **if** your original `array` had dtype=np.int32

Comment: It makes sense. However, I'm not experienced with `numpy.view`s so this is a good opportunity for a second way to solve it (for anyone else maybe).

Comment: @mathfux ok, added examples